# Class inheritance when returning "this" in static and public methods

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance

I'm trying to better understand class inheritance I have some tricks up my sleeve to type static methods, but I wanted to detail a common case I run into and see if there's another way of looking at it.

Here I have a `Root` class these methods I want every class to have, some are public methods (`main` and `fork`) and one static method `main`), each method takes a single argument `props` which is a plain object. Each class adds to this object, specific properties pertaining to that class.

None of these classes need constructors, but I do realize that with this kind of argument inheritance may be useful to use something like `ConstructorParameters<T>[0]`, which I'm open to, i've tried `T['props']` and it's not working.

The main issue is returning `this` rather then `Root` for static and public methods. There is a trick to use `InstanceType<T>` for static methods by using `T extends Root` and defining `this: T`. I'm open to that as well, but then I also need classed-based specific typing for `props`.

I'm open to using a class generic if necessary, but I'd like to steer away from it if I can.

```
class Root {
  props?: {root?: boolean} = {};
  main(props?: Root['props']) {
    this.props = {...this.props, ...props};
    return this;
  }
  fork(props?: Root['props']) {
    return new Root().main({...this.props, ...props});
  }
  static main(props?: Root['props']) {
    return new this().main(props);
  }
}

class Alpha extends Root {
  props?: Root['props'] & {alpha?: boolean};
}

class Beta extends Alpha {
  props?: Alpha['props'] & {beta?: boolean};
}

class Gamma extends Beta {
  props?: Beta['props'] & {gamma?: boolean};
}

const g = Gamma.main({beta: true}); // fails beta & returns instance of Root :(
console.log(g);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKD28Au0DeBYAUNaAHATvLhAPwBcahy50ARoiAKZgB2AvtALxpsDcWOALZgAliwAUBIqQoJkAbQDkU4ooC6ASjQCc0JAAsREAHQqY3VMasGjpwsQA00K3el8dOfIyQBXfCz1DCH5saDYdADN4fABrSXsZOEQkJTN1LQxQz28-AJZGAHck5HENY2ExcUtrINdHZyszNg0QnHDQiCQwJBFgaAqJMxo5FOUE9O0s6C9ff2h8opsIUvLRQYSWnXb2rFBIGABBEFx9MGhGAA8kRhYAExgRyZwh2WTU8bVoADI0MGPTmj0eBMVjuTA7TB7KDQABC3jOl2ud0O-zOmWeCRoRxOYHe0nU3zQtHhgIYzHYIQhUJgAHEwIJhOcrjd7rD4U88JiKHCunjVJ8fqgAOb04Sk4HksFU%20AsTrQIVcaB0hlgVaVVDEroUJD4HyMZq8aAAeiN0AiohAME1Zx%20M1yMDEnVYwEY0HgEWKKDI4l2MogEuMIHgQvEQpaQA)

How can I properly type these methods? As so that `g` is typed as an instance of `Gamma` and the `props` argument to `Gamma.main` is typed to include `gamma`, `beta`, `alpha`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using generics:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwAUBOB7MBnAPAFShAHsBAHYAm6UxEA7lABQB0TAhkgOboBcUzxIAlFAC8APh58xQqAGEUxdMCQBXAMbAUSBK2YBbeBCRZsIgNoAGALoBuALAAoeyoA2zdBQBKKFMBx5CJcihQSBQAMyhPbzEAb3soKBU5BWU1DTowJQAjJwBLFSgwVAxuaNRvAH5uTK8nCF4AX2EoaPrBFts7eJ1mHOJ0ovRK2HhkNCMRNrj4oIALHPQGQrGm6KYGYDmFpYwAGig17fR6jumoJHglJGJZ%20ZOoeqnQjQBrfrGhuEQBnAnmqfjzsBLtcqLRIsA6PwGN1enRVkwNvNFgM9gcBq07g9OlAFMxgHkoDDiL4CEQyBRghAwhEvMARHREVwoNg9ocPiNvsZ%20NwAJLyYC8FQQbDgCA-P7YgEXK6UGg3dCQ6E9PqHQSuKB83HEIUiyA-TH2LGOFxuKAAQScYBmzBJ-nJQVF1ItVuYYlJAQ8tPFsWxiX5KXUSHSWVy%20UO3E%20owwmEp1PBYgAZM1mJbrUNqihag1JpKcUpIEHVZiOka7M5XBQAELwG24d322PhasCt12wLO63e-4JJKKVSB4PZAnh4ZfMYxx3hDuuqBJ6KZGvpmp1YitCWndD5gxvDD8YuG%20zGiuwXTdW1kwKNk86bqti9Vmtd3N%205L9tIZIdhgYRjnjq-Nmc5zYU9mCXTMVzXH0Ny3QsBj3KZjgPBwy17HgmhgEClVheca24PsIFaRxUMydDMKJOEFwFPDlAIqFyJwqighowi7CAA)

```
type GetProps<T extends new (...args: any) => any> = ConstructorParameters<T>[0];

class Root<T extends typeof Root> {
  constructor(public props: {root?: boolean} = {}) {};
  main(props?: GetProps<T>) {
    this.props = {...this.props, ...props};
    return this;
  }
  fork(props?: GetProps<T>) {
    return new Root().main({...this.props, ...props});
  }
  static main<T extends typeof Root>(this: T, props?: GetProps<T>): InstanceType<T> {
    return new this().main(props) as InstanceType<T>;
  }
}

class Alpha<T extends typeof Alpha> extends Root<T> {
  constructor(public props: GetProps<typeof Root> & {alpha?: boolean}) {
    super(props);
  };
}

class Beta<T extends typeof Beta> extends Alpha<T> {
    constructor(public props: GetProps<typeof Alpha> & {beta?: boolean}) {
    super(props);
  };
}

class Gamma<T extends typeof Gamma> extends Beta<T> {
    constructor(public props: GetProps<typeof Beta> & {gamma?: boolean}) {
    super(props);
  };
}

const a = Gamma.main({beta: true})
const b = Gamma.main({beta: true}).main({beta: true})
```